# C++ Binary Search Tree template return Node from function

Tags: c++, templates, binary-search-tree

I've got the following `BinaryTree` class that includes a private class called `Node` (I've omitted everything except what's needed for this question):

```
template<typename T>
class BinaryTree{
private:
    template<typename NT>
    class Node{
    public:
        Node<NT>* left;
        Node<NT>* right;
        NT item;
    };
public:
    Node<T> Find(T itemToFind);
};
```

which is fairly standard. I'm trying to implement the `Node FindMax()` function that returns a `Node` object and I'm unable to figure out how to define it. For example, I assumed (incorrectly) that this would suffice:

```
template<typename T>
Node<T> BinaryTree<T>::Find(T itemToFind){ // -------> error line
    //...do something....
}
```

but I get an error saying: `No template named Node`. I've tried various other combinations to no avail. I'm not looking to return a `bool` if found, I want to return the `Node` itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add scope operator `::` since the `Node` class is part of the `BinaryTree` class:

```cpp
template<typename T>
BinaryTree<T>::Node<T> BinaryTree<T>::Find(T itemToFind) {
    //...do something....
}
```

C++14 introduced `auto` return type so the following will work too:

```cpp
template<typename T>
auto BinaryTree<T>::Find(T itemToFind) {
    //...do something....
}
```

Comment: Technically you can use `auto` if you try hard enough in C++11, but it's just easier to use the actual type in that case.

Answer (score 2):

At that point, the `Node` class is not in scope.  You need to do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
BinaryTree<T>::Node<T> BinaryTree<T>::Find(T itemToFind) { 
    //...do something....
}
```

This was one of the motivations for C++11's trailing return types, which allow you to shorten the return type.  IIRC, the trailing return type for member functions is evaluated within the scope of the class.

```
template<typename T>
BinaryTree<T>::Find(T itemToFind) -> Node<T> { 
    //...do something....
}
```

By the way, do you really want the Node class to have a template parameter that is independent of the template parameter for `BinaryTree`?  That is, you may want to eliminate the second template parameter `NT`.

Comment: I didn't think through that one. I assumed if the outer class has a template parameter, to make the inner class generic I need to add a template as well. I've changed my implementation by removing the template parameter for node and used `T` as `item`'s type. Thanks for the point out!